# How to apply boldface or header formatting to a sentence with LaTeX expression inside?

Tags: latex, markdown, r-markdown, tex

So I'm trying to write up a document in Rstudio, and I have many sentences with in-line LaTeX expressions.  Some of these sentences, I want to either boldface entirely, or make them into document headers.  When I do this, I can only get the normal text to format into boldface, but the LaTeX does not change (it renders, but does not boldface along with the normal text).

A second, but related question--if I want to create ordered lists, or just indent a line with a LaTeX expression *and* have it in boldface, is it possible to do this?

For example:

```
**(a) Prove that $E(b_R) = \beta_1 + P\beta_2$.**

###(a) Prove that $E(b_R) = \beta_1 + P\beta_2$.
```

In both examples, the text "Prove that" correctly goes bold, but the rest does not.  Any advice on the easiest way to get the whole sentence into a consistent look?

For the second case, suppose I want to indent the line and/or I want to have two lines, with the second being part of a list connected to the first.  Is is possible to boldface either of these cases for the entire line, including the LaTex expression.

For the second case:

```
**(a) How to indent this line, and boldface everything: Prove that $E(b_R) = \beta_1 + P\beta_2$.**  

***(a) How can I make this an un-ordered list, all boldface: Prove that $E(b_R) = \beta_1 + P\beta_2$.**    
    **+(a) Can this line be a subpoint to the first, in all boldface? Prove that $E(b_R) = \beta_1 + P\beta_2$.**
```

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some code that automatically switches on `\boldmath` once `\bfseries` is used, c.f. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124311/140850:

```
---
output: pdf_document
---

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\bfseries{\boldmath}
\makeatother

**(a) Prove that $E(b_R) = \beta_1 + P\beta_2$.**

### (a) Prove that $E(b_R) = \beta_1 + P\beta_2$.  

**(a) How to indent this line, and boldface everything: Prove that $E(b_R) = \beta_1 + P\beta_2$.**  

***(a) How can I make this an un-ordered list, all boldface: Prove that $E(b_R) = \beta_1 + P\beta_2$.**    
    **+(a) Can this line be a subpoint to the first, in all boldface? Prove that $E(b_R) = \beta_1 + P\beta_2$.**
```

Output:

[image]

Of course it would be better to add that code to some `tex` file that is included.

Comment: Re:@RalfStubner--Thanks, that worked!  For anyone that is interested, after adding the three lines of suggested code, I was also able to get the ordered list and sub-list point all in bold by using using the '\*' and '+' characters to denote the list as normal, followed by one space after each symbol and then the double '\*\*' around the sentence to make it bold.